# What is the correct way to use javascript to navigate to another page?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, hyperlink

I'm trying to do what I think is a really simple thing, and I can't find any working solutions online.
Basically, I want links in if statements. The pages I want to navigate to are in the same folder as the index-page.

Here are the if-statements:

```
if(cartman > kyle && cartman > stan && cartman > kenny && cartman > butters){
    window.location = 'cartman.html';
}
else if(kyle > cartman && kyle > stan && kyle > kenny && kyle > butters){
    window.location = 'kyle.html';
}
else if(stan > cartman && stan > kyle && stan > kenny && stan > butters){
    window.location = 'stan.html';
}
else if(kenny > cartman && kenny > stan && kenny > kyle && kenny > butters){
    window.location = 'kenny.html';
}
```

I have found many different codes online that are supposed to do this, but none of them have worked. What is the correct way to use javascript to navigate to another page?

Comment: try setting `window.location`.

Comment: What you have tried so far from those online code ?

Comment: Please show us your code. Because `window.location.href = "...";` does indeed work. The problem is not the functions but more likely how you are using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `window.location.replace`:

```
var x = parseInt(prompt();)
if(x === 0) {
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
} else if (x == 1) {
    window.location.replace("http://google.ca");
}
```

Rather than the methods you have tried, `window.location.replace` stimulates a redirect, and pretends you have never left the original page. If you want to stimulate clicking a link, use `window.location.href`.

For more information, see here: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Does that have to be a full address (with http://etc), or can I just use the local relative address (just "cartman.html).

Comment: Remember to upvote any answers that helped you and mark it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(x==1){
    window.location = 'newurl1.html';
}
else if(x==2){
    window.location = 'newurl2.html';
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that one doesn't work either. The this is, if I replace the code where with the link with a simple alert() code, the program works. The alert() window will pop up, so I know that the rest of the code works.

Comment: must be a cross browser thing... As a matter of interest, what browser are you on?